# Use an ApplicationContextListener or @PostConstruct to

Tags: spring

In one of our beans we are reading some file based data in memory.

Would it better to do this from a ApplicationContextListener e.g. calling the beans init() method, or just adding a @PostConstruct to this init() method so the container will do it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:
1. `@PostConstruct`
2. `InitializingBean` interface
3. `<bean class="your bean class" init-method="your init method"/>`

**Attribute : init-method**: The name of the custom initialization method to invoke after 
 setting bean properties. The method must have no arguments, 
 but may throw any exception. This is an alternative to 
 implementing Spring's InitializingBean interface or marking a 
 method with the PostConstruct annotation.

They are alternative: if your program is totally annotated go for annotation, if with XML go for XML (I don't like mixing and you don't need to ask yourself if you implements a feature with annot or xml)

EDIT:

- Context listener: will be called every context refresh (usually once,
  at startup)
- `InitializingBean` or `@PostConstruct`: apply to bean's lifecycle is called every time bean is created (depends by scope)

In your case using a context listener:

1. call init() waits until bean's init() termination, but you are
   sure at which time of container lifecycle it is called.
2. You lost any possibility of lazy-init,
3. but gain possibility to recover from error (maybe accepting to work
   without data in memory)

With `InitializingBean` you :

1. have care bean' scope is "singleton" (else every time you wire the bean, init() method is called),
2. you lost possibility to recovery in case of failure because bean's initialization cycle is not in your hands (or will be more difficult to recover)
3. You gain possibility to lazy-init (startup time is reduced)

In your case, if you are using a singleton bean without lazy-init and don't need error recovery in case of failure, there are not differences at all

Comment: Hi @bellabax, thanks for your reply. I do understand these forms your mentioned can be used to initialize an initializing bean. However my question is more about if there is an architectural difference between using an InitiaizingBean or an ApplicationContextListener for this.

Comment: Edited my answer because write edit in comment results in unreadable text